# How to resize or clear the image of confusion matrix

Tags: python, plot, confusion-matrix

I am using the following code for creating and saving confusion matrix in .png format.

```
from mlxtend.evaluate import confusion_matrix
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_confusion_matrix

cm = confusion_matrix(y_target=y_target, 
                  y_predicted=y_predicted, 
                  binary=False)

fig, ax = plot_confusion_matrix(conf_mat=cm)
plt.savefig('confusion_matrix.png')
```

It is giving good results for less number of classes

[image: Confusion matrix for 3 classe]

But the problem come when number of classes increases and images start getting distorted.

[image]

**QUE:** How can I resize my image to get a good result like this: ( [SOURCE](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1319157819303295?via%3Dihub) of following image)

[image]

Image 1: Image I am getting for less number of classes

Image 2: Image I am getting for larger number of classes

Image 3: Image of what I expect, how it look like when number of classes increase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initializing a subplot variable with a defined figure size will solve your problem.

```
from mlxtend.evaluate import confusion_matrix
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_confusion_matrix
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots

cm = confusion_matrix(y_target=y_target, 
                  y_predicted=y_predicted, 
                  binary=False)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 20))
fig, ax = plot_confusion_matrix(conf_mat=cm, ax=ax)

plt.savefig('confusion_matrix.png')
```

Comment: Thanks, I just add one more parameter for figure size and it works as expected "fig, ax = plot_confusion_matrix(conf_mat=cm, figsize=(20,20))"